# Why Redhat Openstack Platform needs to have Openstack on Director machine?

Tags: redhat, openstack

I want to understand why OpenStack needs to be there on the Director machine on the Redhat Openstack Platform?
Are we going to create VMs on the Director machines as well? I understand the Director machine is used to deploy Overcloud, but that can be achieved by some simple package and without installing the whole Openstack on that single machine.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, that's called TripleO (Openstack-on-Openstack). The Openstack on the Director is only a minimal Openstack. Basically it contains Keystone, Nova, Neutron, Glance, Heat and Ironic.

The director doesn't create VMs. Instead of VMs, the Nova on the director use Ironic to provide baremetal machines for the Overcloud. After Ironic is triggered by Nova, it used Images, which already contains prepared Openstack components, from Glance and copy these images over PXE on the new baremetal-nodes. After this, Heat is triggered to run Heat-templates and Ansible-Playbooks to configure these new deployed baremetal-nodes and create a running Openstack Overclound installation.

It is basically the intention that you only have the install one single director node by hand and all other multi-node Overclouds via the TripleO automation. Beside this it should make the Deployments more scalable, because you could add new Compute-nodes to the Overcloud in the same way like when you create a normal new VM within your Openstack deployment and it should make a version-upgrade of the Overcloud easier.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Followup question: So whenever I expand my overcloud by adding a new physical host, I should be able to see them on Director with "openstack host-list" command and also on overcloud environment? Is this the case for adding  baremetal hosts as well(baremetal for overcloud for end user provisioning)? What installation on baremetal needs to be done in this case?

Comment: Sorry, I can not answer this specific questions. I had only done one initial ReadHat TripleO Installation for some tests a few years ago. So my knowledge is really low. Maybe this link helps you: https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_openstack_platform/9/html/director_installation_and_usage/sect-scaling_the_overcloud

Comment: No issues. Thank you for your comment.